# Large response (250MB+) from server to Chrome Browser becomes null

Tags: jquery, ajax, angular, google-chrome

I have a REST webservice which returns 250MB+ data.

I am trying to get that data in Angular application using HttpClient Get.

When the response size is small, everything is fine, and data can be seen in the browser, but if it is 250MB+ then the response becomes null.

Developer tools, displays the data size downloaded, but nothing is displayed in "response tab".

[image]

I have even tried replacing the angular http client get by JQuery AJAX, same result.

I am guessing this is a browser issue and not the technology we are using.

Any idea, why this must be happening?

Thanks

Comment: This could be an issue in the backend. Did you check the response in Postman or something similar? Does it work then?

Comment: Backend is returning data, Postman works fine. even I can see the data getting downloaded in dev tools

Answer (score -1):

The reason could be because the user interface thread cannot handle that much of data. You can use [web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) to achieve this.

> Web Workers is a simple means for web content to run scripts in background threads. The worker thread can perform tasks without interfering with the user interface

[This](https://blog.angularindepth.com/angular-with-web-workers-step-by-step-dc11d5872135) might help for you to integrate web workers into your angular project.